# Access to Hashmap value in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

When I create this objects, i do like this:

```
random_fields= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

try {
    // Getting Array of fields
    JSONArray fields= json.getJSONArray("fields");

    // Looping through All fields
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jobj = fields.getJSONObject(i);

        // Creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map_aux = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map_aux.put("field_id", jobj.getString("field_id"));

        map_aux.put("field_text", jobj.getString("field_text"));
    }    
    // Adding HashList to ArrayList
    random_fields.add(map_aux);
}
```

And then when I try to access to every single field in the Arraylist of Hashmaps... i do like this:

For example:

```
editText1.setText(random_fields.get(0).get("field_text"));
```

and it gives me a Java Null Pointer Error... but if I do:

```
System.out.println(random_challenges.get(0).get("field_text"));
```

It works and it prints in my debug console.. the field text correctly.. Which can be the solution?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your posts. You should have been able to see from the preview that your code was *miles* over to the right, scrolling for no reason. Additionally, please use spaces rather than tabs for indentation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You setText with  `random_fields` but printing `random_challenges` ?

Comment: Be sure about that your program never throw exception. If it throws, it is possible to be `random_fields.get(0).get("field_text") = null`

Answer (score 0):

The code where you set your editText looks right. The only difference I can spot here is that you use random_challenges in your System.out.println method and random_fields in your setText method.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to provide some actual code files (not just the snippets) and I can look closer, but from what you have provided I would venture to guess that what is happening is that the values you think you are populating your hash map with (in the for loop) go out of scope and are cleaned up leaving you with the NULL reference.

You console, since it persists, keeps the data instantiated long enough for you to debug print it.